# Count the number of email campaigns clicked by a user within one query

Tags: django, django-models, group-by, distinct, django-orm

What I intend to do is something like this:

`Clicks.objects.filter(campaign_id__in=[1,2,3]).distinct('campaign', 'subscriber').annotate(campaigns_clicked=Count('subscriber'))`

But django returns with the error: `NotImplementedError: annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.`

A subscriber can have multiple clicks for one campaign and one campaign can have clicks for multiple subscribers. Amongst the clicking subscribers, I want to know how many campaigns each subscriber clicked.

Is there a workaround to get this result within one query?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this. Since annotate and distinct cant be chained in the same query, I used one as a subquery for another, like so:

`Clicks.objects.filter(id__in=Clicks.objects.filter(campaign_id__in=[1,2,3]).distinct('campaign', 'subscriber').values_list('id', flat=True)).values_list('subscriber').annotate(campaigns_clicked=Count('subscriber')`